# Playing large videos online

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video, red5, flowplayer

I have a few videos (avi, mp4, mkv) each is around 1 GB and I have one around 7 GB.

I want to play these videos online, so I tried FlowPlayer which seems to be broken with videos larger than 600MB.

is there any solution that will allow me to play these videos online? without converting to flv as I intend to allow downloads for these videos too.

I've been thinking of red5, but I don't know if it will work for this kind of videos nor if it works with the above-mentioned extensions + I am not familiar on how to make its applications and get direct downloads links (I don't want duplicated files for watch/download).

I will also need a timed captioning support like '.srt' files.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a web-based player that supports all of the features you mention.  However, you can get folks to install VLC's browser plugin.  This is not ideal, as most folks won't do this, but it will do what you ask.

Otherwise, I suggest keeping the original available for download, and converting the videos to FLV as well.  For the captions, you will need to convert the file to whatever format the player you end up using supports.

For the player, I recommend looking into [Longtail](http://www.longtailvideo.com/).

Comment: Converted videos will take around 50% of the original files disk space, which will be too much in my case.
And I have tried to convert a video using ffmpeg and it has throw-in an error regarding 6 channels audio And I don't seem to find any program that is able to convert these videos.
I have another question though will converting a video break the captions? or it should work fine?